# Vertical Spacing between Div needs to be removed

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am new to Web Dev, and i am facing an issue wrt to Div : https://jsfiddle.net/debashis_gt540m/17mmmxps/2/
The three div's at the end have some amount of spacing in between them, I've tried with inserting all 3 div's within a single one, but it didn't help. Anyone ? I want to get rid of the spaces between the 3 div's.
The code is:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="https://in.linkedin.com/in/debdebashis"   target="_blank">Debashis Deb</a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#">Home</a>
       </li>
        <li><a href="#" class="text-primary">About Me</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Skills</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Interests</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact Me</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</a>
        </li>
      </ul></div>
  </div>
</nav>
<div>
<div class="container-fluid bg-1 well">
     <div class="row">

     </div>

</div>
<div class="container-fluid bg-2 well">
</div>
<div class="container-fluid bg-3 well">
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.well {
    margin-bottom: 0px !important;
}
```

Comment: i removed the well, and it worked. guess the margin-bottom property was causing the issue ! thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

the 3 divs have bottom margins, that's what adding the space. add this css:

```
.container-fluid{margin-bottom:0px;}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, but still there is some amount of space in between the divs !